# Ionic 7 with Angular makes only UI changes when Debbuger ist runing

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I have an ion-select which should contain an ion-icon at the end. The icon should change depending on whether the ion-select is open or closed.
Problem:
My icon changes correctly when the ion-select is open but no longer when the ion-select is closed. Strangely enough, when I debug the behaviour, the ion-icon changes correctly both when closing and opening.

```
<ion-list lines="none">
      <ion-list-header class="header">{{'category' | translate }}</ion-list-header>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-select placeholder="{{'categoryFilter' | translate }}" interface="popover" (ionFocus)="setToggleIcon()" (ionDismiss)="setExpandIcon()" >
          <ion-select-option  *ngFor="let category of [1,2,3]; index as i">Apfel {{i}}</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
        <ion-icon class="toggleIcon" name="{{toggleIcon}}"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <hr class="border">
      </ion-list>



@Component({
  selector: 'app-maintenance-list',
  templateUrl: './maintenance-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maintenance-list.component.scss'],
})
export class MaintenanceListComponent  implements OnInit {
  protected toggleIcon:string = "chevron-down-outline";
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {}

  setToggleIcon(): void {
    this.toggleIcon = 'chevron-up-outline';
  }

  setExpandIcon(){
    this.toggleIcon ="chevron-down-outline"
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

OK below are the two things I noticed.

1. the property `toggleIcon` is protected, when it should be public since its used in the HTML and needs to be used outside the class!
2. You can try using `ionBlur` intead of `ionDismiss`, when I changed that it started working fine!

[ion select docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#events)

html

```
<ion-list lines="none">
  <ion-list-header class="header">{{ 'category' }}</ion-list-header>
  <ion-item tabindex="1">
    <ion-select
      placeholder="{{ 'categoryFilter' }}"
      interface="popover"
      (ionFocus)="setToggleIcon()"
      (ionBlur)="setExpandIcon()"
    >
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let category of [1, 2, 3]; index as i"
        >Apfel {{ i }}</ion-select-option
      >
    </ion-select>
    <ion-icon class="toggleIcon" name="{{ toggleIcon }}"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
  <hr class="border" />
</ion-list>
```

ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public toggleIcon: string = 'chevron-down-outline';
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}

  setToggleIcon(): void {
    this.toggleIcon = 'chevron-up-outline';
  }

  setExpandIcon() {
    this.toggleIcon = 'chevron-down-outline';
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-e1d2ue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: With ionBlur, the icon is converted back to its normal form immediately after opening, as the focus is no longer on the ion-select but on the popover.

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted the method so that it always changes the icon to the opposite. So everything works correctly.
HTML:

```
<ion-list lines="none">
      <ion-list-header class="header">{{'category' | translate }}</ion-list-header>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-select placeholder="{{'categoryFilter' | translate }}" interface="popover" (ionFocus)="setToggleIcon()" (ionCancel)="setToggleIcon()" >
          <ion-select-option  *ngFor="let category of [1,2,3]; index as i">Apfel {{i}}</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
        <ion-icon class="toggleIcon" name="{{toggleIcon}}"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <hr class="border">
      </ion-list>
```

TS:

```
export class MaintenanceListComponent  implements OnInit {
toggleIcon:string = "chevron-down-outline";
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {}

  setToggleIcon(): void {
    if(this.toggleIcon === 'chevron-up-outline'){
      this.toggleIcon = 'chevron-down-outline';
    }else{
      this.toggleIcon = 'chevron-up-outline';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't say why my previous solution only worked when the debugger was on.